# Conditional union in SQL Server until it reaches a specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with dates from first of previous year till last month i.e., Jan 2015 to Sep 2016.

I have to perform a two months comparison in the same table as below i. e., select all rows in Jan month from `table1` except rows in Feb month from table 1 ; select all rows in Feb month except rows in march month from `table1`.....

Till it reaches last month.

Here I need do conditional union for each two month comparison till it reaches last month.

***Sample:***

```
select col1,col2 from table1 where month=jan 2015 
except 
select col1,col2 from table1 where month=feb 2015
union
select col1,col2 from table1 where month=feb 2015 
except 
select col1,col2 from table1 where month=mar 2015
.
.
.
union
select col1,col2 from table1 where month=aug 2016 
except 
select col1,col2 from table1 where month=sep 2016
```

***Sample data:***

```
Customer    Product       date       amount
-------------------------------------------    
a           p1            1/31/2015  $12
a           p2            1/31/2015  $13
a           p2            2/28/2015  $1
```

So here product p1 exist in jan and no longer in feb 2015. So I need all products in Jan which are not there in Feb 2015 ....

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: This makes to sense. What are you really trying to achieve business wise?

Comment: For some data cleanup

Comment: Can col1,col2 repeat at all in the requested result set? E.g., If a combination exists in Jan, can it also exist in may? Also, Can it exists twice in Jan? Do we want to eliminate all duplicates?

Comment: Nope only one combination for each product and customer exists for one month.

Comment: And between months? Any limitations?

Comment: If the customer purchased the same product say p1 up to say march 2015 and then stopped purchasing the product p1, then there won't be any entry in the table. So I need all such rows where the product p1 stopped ...

Comment: So basically, everything that apears no matter where but doesn't apear in the last month?

Comment: I want rows that are in one month but not the next month for each year except Jan and Dec months as we have fresh sales every year and Jan and Dec sales will not have issues.

Comment: 1. I understand about Dec but not Jan. If a product apears on Jan but not Feb, is it O.k.? 2. Do we curreny have a case where product apears in Jan and March but not Feb?

Comment: For 1) yes 2) not possible as per our data

Comment: You do know it is just processed in order.  The except is not going to just honor the union above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you appear to have all data in a single table.  Under such circumstances, `union all` (and related operations) are not usually necessary.

Second, you seem to want rows that are in one month but not the next month.

I would think something like this:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t2
                  where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and
                        t2.month = t.month + 1
                 ) and
      month >= jan 2015 and
      month <= sep 2016;
```

Of course, you haven't shown what the *data* actually looks like, so I don't know what `t.month + 1` really should look like.  But the idea is to add one month to the "month" value.

Comment: Added sample data. Can you please advise.

Comment: @bipro . . . This answer pretty much does what you want.  You just have to fix the date arithmetic to match your data.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

#### These are the good

```
select      *

from       (select      t.*
                       ,max (sale_month) over (partition by customer_id,product_id,sale_year)  as last_sale_month_of_year

            from        t
            ) t

where       t.last_sale_month_of_year in (1,12) -- Jan,Dec
        or  (    sale_year                  = year(getdate())
             and last_sale_month_of_year    = moth(getdate()) 
            )
;
```

#### These are the bad

```
select      *

from       (select      t.*
                       ,max (sale_month) over (partition by customer_id,product_id,sale_year)  as last_sale_month_of_year

            from        t
            ) t

where       t.last_sale_month_of_year not in (1,12) -- Jan,Dec
        and  (   sale_year                  <> year(getdate())
             or  last_sale_month_of_year    <> moth(getdate()) 
            )
;
```